# Make query_post category name dynamic

Tags: query-posts

I have a working funtion:

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=category');?>
```

I want to make the category name dynamic to reflect the page title.  Something like this:

```
<?php query_posts('category_name='.the_title());?>
```

But this doesnt work, & nothing I do seems to have the desired effect.

Comment: So you have created page with the same text used for category, and you want to query posts by the page title as category name ? if that's the question, the your approach is correct. You just need to change `'category_name='.the_title()` to `'category_name='. get_the_title()`. Also as you are making query from a **Page**, you need to pass the post type, so it would be `'category_name='. get_the_title() . '&post_type=post'`.

Comment: yes get_the_title instead of the_title - works.  If you make an answer I will accept. Thanks

Comment: [Please do not use `query_posts`.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A21376+query_posts)

Comment: Ok but it would have been a bit easier with code!  <?php  $the_query = new WP_Query('category_name='. get_the_title());  if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :  while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>      <?php endwhile;  wp_reset_postdata();  endif; ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `get_the_title()` replacing `the_title()`. Difference is `get_the_title()` returns the value while `the_title()` echos it.